# How to insert Russian characters in to sql server table

Tags: c#, sql, collation

i was trying to insert russian character in to sql table with data type as Nvarchar(max)

when i insert russian value "Македонски" after insertion  the table values become   "??????????" .
i cannot change my c#code of insertion to N'Македонски' as the code is in production.
i saw a suggestion in the internet to change sql collation to "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS" for the column to allow russian and english language.but changing the collation to "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS" is not working.

i tried collation change to "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" but that too proved failure
any work around to fix this

Comment: Change collation is not a solution. Tomorrow you will need to insert Armenian word. Check how you prepare insert statement in C#. Most probably it is `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",DBType.VarChar)`. Change `VarChar` to `NVarChar`

Answer (score 2):

You need  N'russian word' for any insert into a column that is Unicode nchar/nvarchar. FOr every letters for outside ASCII.

Comment: but i have to stop my production code and re deploy to do that.is there any other work around to fix this? something like trigger to add prefix N before insertion or changing collation